# How do I create a web page in CRM that talks the web service for both IFD and On-premise?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

We have three servers that all share the same database. One server is internet facing.

I have a web page in an IFRAME in CRM that talks to the CRM web service using the standard method of connecting for on-premise. When this IFRAME is displayed through the IFD with users logged in through the forms authentication element, you are asked for login credentials.

How do I get around this?

EDIT

The IFRAME that targets the CRM service is on four servers. Two of the servers are used for IFD and On-premise use. The other two are for on-premise only. They are all in the same domain. All of the users are internal users that can log in through the web if they are using a customer's computer or a machine in an Internet cafe and therefore can't use the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions to better understand you issue. Is the iframe which targets CrmService on the same IFD server? Is the IFD server on the same domain as the rest of the servers? When you say users are logged in are you refereeing to local domain users or external users?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not the services, but the IFrame. When you authenticate to MSCRM via on-premise you are doing Windows Authentication, and when you should the IFrame that authentication request is done again. Since the browser knows everything it needs this is all handled transparently.

When using IFD, you are not using authentication on the web server level - you are doing it using forms based which is on the application level. You IFrame though is still wanting authentication, and thus the iframe prompts for authentication.

If you were having a service problem, the IFrame would display and what ever action triggers the service call would fail with a 400 or 500 error.

So the question comes in how do you build a web page that can cater for windows authentication and forms based? Well that is easy in MSCRM, first make sure you are not running authentication on the web page - set it to anonymous. That ensures no more popups, then make sure you use the CrmAuthenticationToken code to get the token and use that for all calls. You should not be setting the .Credentials property of the service itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're deploying your page within the CRM website (and not its own virtual directory) then here is pointing you at the SDK article for what Robert mentioned:

See the SDK topic titled:  Authentication from an ASPX Page.

In my experience you should always use the CRMImpersonator in your web pages within the CRM website.

Now if you've got your own page running on its own website:
You'll want to see the Discovery service and obtaining a CRM Ticket for accessing the services.